# to implement reset in stopwatch

Tags: javascript, stopwatch

I have a javascript stopwatch and i have start and stop but i like to add another button reset pls help me to solve this issue.I have  placed the javascript below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var c=0;
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timedCount()
{
document.getElementById('txt').value=c;
c=c+1;
t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
}

function doTimer()
{
if (!timer_is_on)
  {
  timer_is_on=1;
  timedCount();
  }
}

function stopCount()
{
clearTimeout(t);
timer_is_on=0;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Start count!" onClick="doTimer()">
<input type="text" id="txt">
<input type="button" value="Stop count!" onClick="stopCount()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" value="reset count!" onClick="resetCount()">
```

**JS:**

```
function resetCount() {
     document.getElementById('txt').value =0;
    c =0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UrUE6/)